# Thunar is not showing any thumbnails

Tags: images, xfce, thumbnails, thunar

I was looking for the `gnome-exe-thumbnailer` (or similar) package in Fedora 20 (which surprinsingly wasn't in the repos) but I found `tumbler-extras`, which I installed and almost immediately uninstalled; then Thunar was unable to generate new thumbnails.

I've made everything described here: [Why is Thunar not creating and showing thumbnails of images?](https://superuser.com/questions/258633/why-is-thunar-not-creating-and-showing-thumbnails-of-images)

I've also made a rollback to just before `tumbler-extras` was installed, but anything seems to be solving this issue.

---

I've just found out that this issue is caused by selinux. I've already filed a [bug #1058064](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1058064) on redhat's bugzilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arch you also need to install [ffmpegthumbnailer](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=ffmpegthumbnailer) for Thunar to do thumbs in addition to tumbler.  Perhaps looking for the equivalent package in Fedora will do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, I've that package installed as well, but the problem is selinux. If I have it on "disabled" mode, thumbnailers work fine, but when on "enforcing" mode, no thumbnails are created at all. I've already reported this on bugzilla. bug #1058064.

Comment: Ok, right on - you're welcome!